# Compiling against android MNC impossible?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have follow the instructions on 
https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Can't really get it working with below error in android studio (update to 1.3RC-2)

[image: Error]

[image]

I have tried with "minSdkVersion MNC", still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should missed the single quotes around "android-MNC", it should be:

compileSdkVersion **'android-MNC**', not compileSdkVersion android-MNC